# Run-time Error 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, mailmerge

I have 2 separate word documents with Mail Merge lists. And I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets. Based on the worksheet name & if the sheet is not empty, I need to send the mailmerge to that respective word document(s).

When I try to execute this code, it runs upto the first document and at the second document, it stops with an error `Run-time Error 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set`

I'm not sure what's causing this error (if it's the Dim variable or With block). Would greatly appreciate if someone could kindly help me rectify this error.

```
Sub Generate_Certificate() 

    Dim wd As Object 
    Dim wdoc_reg As Object 
    Dim wdoc_occ As Object 
    Dim strWbName_reg As String 
    Dim strWbName_occ As String 


    Const wdFormLetters = 0, wdOpenFormatAuto = 0 
    Const wdFormLetters1 = 0, wdOpenFormatAuto1 = 0 
    Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0, wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord = -16 
    Const wdSendToNewDocument1 = 0, wdDefaultFirstRecord1 = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord1 = -16 


    On Error Resume Next 
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 
    If wd Is Nothing Then 
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    End If 
    On Error Goto 0 


    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets 

         'Generate report using "Mailmerge" if any data available for Mailmerge1
        If Sheet.Name Like "Sheet1" And IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value) = False Then 
            Set wdoc_reg = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Mailmerge1.docx") 


            strWbName_reg = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name 


            wdoc_reg.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters 


            wdoc_reg.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _ 
            Name:=strWbName_reg, _ 
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _ 
            Revert:=False, _ 
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _ 
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWbName_reg & ";Mode=Read", _ 
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`" 

            With wdoc_reg.MailMerge 
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument 
                .SuppressBlankLines = True 
                With .DataSource 
                    .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord 
                    .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord 
                End With 
                .Execute Pause:=False 
            End With 


            wd.Visible = True 
            wdoc_reg.Close SaveChanges:=False 


            Set wdoc_reg = Nothing 
            Set wd = Nothing 
        End If 


         'Generate report using "Mailmerge" if any data available for Mailmerge2
        If Sheet.Name Like "Sheet2" And IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value) = False Then 
            Set wdoc_occ = wd.Documents.Open("C:\Mailmerge2.docx") 


            strWbName_occ = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name 


            wdoc_occ.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters1 


            wdoc_occ.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _ 
            Name:=strWbName_Occ, _ 
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _ 
            Revert:=False, _ 
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto1, _ 
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWbName_occ & ";Mode=Read", _ 
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`" 


            With wdoc_occ.MailMerge 
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument1 
                .SuppressBlankLines = True 
                With .DataSource 
                    .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord1 
                    .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord1 
                End With 
                .Execute Pause:=False 
            End With 


            wd.Visible = True 
            wdoc_occ.Close SaveChanges:=False 


            Set wdoc_Occ = Nothing 
            Set wd = Nothing 
        End If 


    Next 


End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Set wd = Nothing` inside your loop, which will clear your reference to Word after the first sheet.  Move that to just before the `End Sub`

Comment: Thank you soooo much, Tim!! You're the best!!
I deleted that line, and my code worked like magic!! Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Tim Williams in the question's comments.

> You have `Set wd = Nothing` inside your loop, which will clear your reference to Word after the first sheet. Move that to just before the `End Sub`